# how to port forward an https website

Tags: https

I have recently got an SSL certificate on my website, on the apache server that I am using to host my website. The website says "Secure" and also works fine when I run it over localhost using the laptops ip address 192.168.*.**. But when I try to port forward this website over the port 443, it somehow says unsecure and your connection is not private. Any help here will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are using a self-signed certificate for your https connection. While modern browsers such as chrome give you errors saying the connection is unsecure and perhaps you even see red lines crossing out the https at the beginning of your url, there is no need to worry. If you are getting your page to render with these characteristics all is working, the reason for the errors is because the certificate is signed only for you.

In a real world production scenario you would have to use a third party service for a public capable certificate. However for your own development purposes, as long as the page runs with https there all is working as it is intended to.

For more try reading [this](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/ssl/self-signed-ssl-certificate-warning) article.

Comment: thank you very much for the help. Really helped me a lot.